# Hide Location Service Popup Window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, popup

I am a newbie in iphone development and obj-c. Can you help me to hide the Location Service Popup Window at the time of Application Start in iphone and ipad.It will show only once for an application at the time of first deployment.i think it is the reason of "ALAssetLibrary" which i used for retrieving images from  Photo library.

could tell me in the correct way to Hide Location Service Popup Window, and if possible any sample code to get my started.

Thank You In Advance

Comment: Are u using GPS service of iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That popup is coming because of "ALAssetLibrary" this is coming because you are using GPS in your application. There is no way to hide this dialog it will appear only the first time to ask the user does he wants to send their GPS data to app or not. There is no way to hide it.. Also the apple may reject your app if they don't find this dialog if you are using GPS data.

Comment: thanks..can i use ALAssetLibrary(only ALAssetPropertyURLs) without using location service.

Comment: could tell me the way to avoid location service.

Comment: My code is :NSURL *imageurl = [dict objectForKey: [youSaid text]]; typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)(ALAsset *asset);
typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)(NSError *error);    
two blocks
if(imageurl != nil)
{
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetLibrary assetForURL:i

Comment: search this delegate in your project and comment it out - - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

Comment: also comment all the location manage delegate you can find them here - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html

Comment: i think when app loads the old location is nil.but this need a parameter called "New location" which is not nil.

Comment: i think it will call default at the time of app starts.thats the reason of popup

Comment: could tell me where will the delegate(which class).

Comment: search - startUpdatingLocation and stopUpdatingLocation in your project and comment them

Comment: i didn't get.there is no startUpdatingLocation in my project.. is it in ALassetLibrary class?

Comment: searched in my project .i added assetLibrary frame work.so i think this delegate will be inside of that frame work..i think we can't get that method.can i access that delegate?

Comment: how ca i get this delegate from ALAssetLibrary